# SQL search between values in DB (Zipcode)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a code that provide basic information about the place you live in, in the Netherlands.

There for i need the 'id' from a zip code that can vary between zip A (1234) of zip B (1236). Those begin and end numbers are already in the database. But I failed to get the id, because i'm getting an error with the SQL syntax.

I have tried to do the following:

```
SELECT `id` WHERE `9291` BETWEEN 'zipA' AND 'zipB'
SELECT `id` WHERE `zipA` > '9291' OR `zipB` < '9291'
SELECT `id` WHERE `zipA` > '9291' AND `zipB` < '9291'
```

What could i do to make this work? I'm just a beginner with MYSQL and php, i'm currently working with CodeIgniter 2.1.0

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post you table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `id` WHERE `9291` BETWEEN 'zipA' AND 'zipB'
SELECT `id` WHERE `9291` BETWEEN 'zipA' AND 'zipB'
SELECT `id` WHERE `zipA` > '9291' AND `zipB` < '9291'
```

A couple of things:

- You cannot compare an integer value to a char/varchar value. It
     looks to me like you are trying to compare the column `9291` to the
     string values 'zipA' AND 'zipB'.
- Be careful with your backticks / single quotes.
- Where is your FROM statement? You are selecting column `id` FROM ?

Could you please try something like this:

```
SELECT
   id
FROM
   zip_code_table
WHERE
   zip BETWEEN 9000 AND 9100
```

Comment: The zipA and zipB where examples and contain the values of a zipcode (like 1234).

Comment: You were right, i completely missed the from statement, with this i can manage the data through objects. Thank you very much!

Comment: awesome, be careful with your backticks \` and your single quotes '.